# why am I not getting removed the rows based on the given job titles?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to delete the job_titles which are not listed on my job title array, and I would like to fix it

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    var keywords = ['aslr', 'ida pro', 'gdb', 'windbg', 'immunity debugger', 'boofuzz', 'peach fuzzer', 'winafl', 'python', 'assembly', 'penetration testing', 'exploits', 'metasploit', 'metasploit framework', 'ethical hacker', 'pentest', 'computer security', 'hacking', 'oscp', 'osce', 'osee', 'penetration testing', 'offensive security', 'mitre att&ck', 'vulnerability research', 'vulnerability researcher', 'fuzzing', 'clang', 'llvm', 'address sanitizer', 'afl', 'fuzzers','penetration tester']
    var job_title = ['penetration tester','penetration testing', 'offensive security', 'vulnerability researcher','software','security','developer','ethical hacker','cyberSécurité','threat','it Security','application security','information security','security engineer','product security','cyber security','software engineer']
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/index_get_data",
            "dataType": "json",
            "dataSrc": "jobs",
            "contentType":"application/json"
        },
        columnDefs: [{
            targets: 0,
            rowCallback: function (data,row) {
              for (var i = 0; i < job_title.length; i += 1) {
                if (data.indexOf(job_title[i])) {
                  // dont nothing
                }
              }
              return $(row).hide();
            }
        }
```

Comment: You don't need to iterate through job_titles array, just use includes() function to check data is in array or not, like "job_title .includes(data)".

Comment: why isnt removing?

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by removing?

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, you **want to check the data(job_tilte) is exist in job_title array**.
You can use **includes() method** to do it, the *includes() method determines whether an array contains a specified element*.

```
job_title.includes(data)
```

Please check the below link: 
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes_array.asp

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right,

```
      rowCallback: function (data,row) {
          if(!job_title.includes(data)){
            return $(row).hide() 
          }
        }
```